# VirtualBox VM in VirtualBox VM

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox on Mac running Windows 7 (1). The problem is that the Windows 7 has a environment that launches a VirtualBox VM with Linux (2), and it crashes the VirtualBox (1). Does anyone have a running enviroment with a VirtualBox VM inside another VirtualBox VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple... I just added the VirtualVM (2) in Mac, and connected them via network...